# Julia DataFrame ERROR: BoundsError attempt to access attempt to access a data frame with X rows at index false

Tags: julia

I'm trying to subset a DataFrame in Julia as follows:

```
df = DataFrame(a=[1,2,3], b=["x", "y", "z"])
df2 = df[df.a == 2, :]
```

I'd expect to get back just the second row, but instead I get an error:

> ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access "attempt to access a data frame
>   with 3 rows at index false"

What does this error mean and how do I subset the DataFrame?

Comment: Why do you keep asking and answering your own questions?

Comment: To make it easier for other people to google errors to common mistakes and find answers more quickly. My understanding is that this is encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention other options note that you can use the `filter` function here:

```
julia> filter(row -> row.a == 2, df)
1×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b      │
│     │ Int64 │ String │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ y      │
```

or

```
julia> df[filter(==(2), df.a), :]
1×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b      │
│     │ Int64 │ String │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ y      │
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, you only need to add one character: `.`. The `.` character enables broadcasting on any Julia function, even ones like `==`. Therefore, your code would be as follows:

```
df = DataFrame(a=[1,2,3], b=["x", "y", "z"])
df2 = df[df.a .== 2, :]
```

Without the broadcast, the clause `df.a == 2` returns `false` because it's literally comparing the Array [1,2,3], as a whole unit, to the scalar value of 2. An Array of shape (3,) will never be equal to a scalar value of 2, without broadcasting, because the sizes are different. Therefore, that clause just returns a single `false`.

The error you're getting tells you that you're trying to access the DataFrame at index `false`, which is not a valid index for a DataFrame with 3 rows. By broadcasting with `.`, you're now creating a Bool Array of shape (3,), which is a valid way to index a DataFrame with 3 rows.

For more on broadcasting, see the official Julia documentation [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1).